# Cookies not being passed from response to next request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, web, cookies

I'm trying to build my first Web app and I am using cookies for authentication.

Basically, my React client sends the auth credentials to my REST API which verifies it and generates a token if the credentials are valid.

When I inspect the network activity on chrome, the token is set on the response header of the `/login` POST request, but when I try to access a protected route after this, I get a 401 and inspecting the request reveals that the cookie was not present on the header.

How do I combat this? I thought this was a CORS issue at first but I just cannot seem to solve it.

Response of the login call:
[image]

Cookie missing on the next request:
[image]

How I've handled the CORS issue:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Set-Cookie");
next();
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your next `POST` request to protected route doesn't contain the cookie, because by default it doesn't send the cookies.

If you're using axios.

set `withCredentials: true`

```js
axios.get(`api_url`, { withCredentials: true })
```

By setting `{ withCredentials: true }` you may encounter cross-origin issue. To solve that you need to use

```js
expressApp.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:8080" })); //Your REACT ADDRESS
```

Read more about withCredentials here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Answer (score 0):

The issue must be because of Set-cookie attribute **SameSite=strict**. SameSite attribute works in following way.

**SameSite= samesite-value**

**Strict:** The browser sends the cookie only for same-site requests (that is, requests originating from the same site that set the cookie). If the request originated from a different URL than the current one, no cookies with the SameSite=Strict attribute are sent.

**Lax:** The cookie is withheld on cross-site subrequests, such as calls to load images or frames, but is sent when a user navigates to the URL from an external site, such as by following a link.

**None:** The browser sends the cookie with both cross-site and same-site requests.

In your case subsequent request is also cross origin so browser doesn't attach cookie in the header. It should work if **SameSite=None**